# <c:out> tag inside <input> tag not working

Tags: jsp, jstl

After using <input type="hidden" name="contactId" value="**<c:out value="${contactForm.contactId}"/>**">

My App is not working giving 404 error.
Can any one tell me the reason behind this?
and please tell me the solution this.

Thanks,
Amresh

Comment: Are you sure it's giving 404 error?  If yes then the code you are saying doesn't cause that error instead it simply means page you are redirecting is not found or exist .

Comment: Your question does not contain the detailed information. Please add more information. The issue you are mentioning is related to the routing and not what is inside the page.